# Is there any documentation for dnnlib: additional lib in projects of NVlabs?

Tags: tensorflow, configuration, documentation, nvidia, lib

There is special unified lib named **dnnlib** in noted projects from NVlabs like Noise2Noise, StyleGAN and etc. It seems like this lib was made for parsing and easy configuration, but it also participates in creating and managing tensorflow sessions. Mentioned projects are well commented, but from this point it is hard to use some of parts, like this lib, in sided or pet-projects. Is there any special documentation for except the code on Github?

Comment: Have you found anything about dnnlib usage?

Answer (score 0):

I also looked around a little while for this. It doesn't appear there is any documentation other than code/comments/docstrings themselves. My best guess is that either nvidia has some internal docs for it that it hasn't made public or that the creators simply didn't go through the work of making it a proper open-source library for general usage. Hopefully this will change!